# Laravel+Passport as oAuth server and axios+cordova as a client

Tags: cordova, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, axios, laravel-passport

***Hello Coders***,

My goal is to make an API on laravel so user get/post the data on other device /client. Client code is on axios+cordova. Am I on correct path or doing wrong. First time on Laravel + Passport API as well as on axios + cordova also.

**Server Side**

> I setup server with the help of Laravel 5.6.4 + Passport and created token on Postman successfully.

[image: oauth token]

**Client Side**

> Now I am trying to access user data through api/user default route in separate project, here is my code for that

```
AUTH_TOKEN                                     =    'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ...';

axios.defaults.baseURL                         =    'http://sbs-api.dev';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =    AUTH_TOKEN;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type']    =    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

axios.get('/api/user')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

> but I'm unable to get user data instead of getting this error Network Error and/or Preflight Error. On Postman I am getting the data with same token.

[image]

> ***Please tell me what is wrong with this code and/or provide some tutorials if possible.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Okay my bad here is the reason why am I getting issue, I was using virtual url http://sbs-api.dev instead of original url http://localhost/sbs-api/public**
>
> My sincere apology for this stupid and simple mistake O.o :)

[image: wrong path]